# Efficiently getting updated about part of the data in another microservice's database in realtime

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices

I have an "Inventory" microservice, and I need another "algorithm" microservice to get all the serial numbers in the inventory's mc database pretty much in real-time in order to perform it's calculations.

I thought about using Kafka Connector to keep track of the changes in the DB, But a problem arose that I am not sure how to solve:

How do I get the initial state?

- The Kafka Connector will only emit changes.
- If I use, say, a REST API request, then I will have a hard time knowing when I should start "listening" to the topic, as it may change while the request is happening.
- I can periodically/by demand publish a "snapshot", but I fear it may get too big for Kafka.

Comment: Typically, change data capture systems will publish a snapshot of the DB records when they start (and sometimes when they detect that they might have missed updates).

Comment: Debezium can make an initial snapshot. Have you tried using it?

Comment: And rather than using a consumer behind a REST API, perhaps using server sent events or a websocket would be better

Comment: Thank you. About the snapshot, it I'm correct Kafka has a 1MB limit, so how can it work with large databases?

Comment: In debezium's case, the snapshot will be dumped row by row, and then you get one record per transaction.